# How to keep my code "fully Scala" in this WebDriverWait example?

Tags: java, scala, selenium, webdriver, overriding

See the line that starts with `override def...`? I'd like for it not to be in Java style and instead be able to do `driver.findElementByClassName()` like normal. But when I change `driver: WebDriver` to `driver: FirefoxDriver`, I get complaints about the override, and I remove that, then I get complaints about apply.

Any ideas? I know Selenium fairly well, but am new to Java and Scala (I come from a Python background).

Thanks!

```
import org.junit.{Before, After, Test}
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.{WebDriverWait, ExpectedCondition}
import org.openqa.selenium.{By, WebDriver, WebElement}

class WebDriverWaitTesting extends DemoHelpers {
  @Before
  lazy val driver = adminLogin(setup())

  @Test
  def CompanySelectorAfterLogin() {
    val wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
      new ExpectedCondition[WebElement] {
        override def apply(driver: WebDriver) = driver.findElement(By.className("company-selector-link"))
      }
    )
    assert(driver.getPageSource() contains "Select Company", "We are not on the Company Selector page")
  }

  @After
  def after() {
    tearDown(driver)
  }
}
```

Comment: It was already apparent from the subject that you're coming from Python. My brain automatically translated "fully Scala" into "scalonic".